# Flattening a nested dictionary with System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, system.text.json

I'm trying to port the last piece of code I have that is dependent on `Newtonsoft.Json` to `System.Text.Json`.

The code parses a JSON fragment and flattens it. This is generated by a legacy system so we'd rather not change that if possible.

```
// Comment here including the person who last made a change to the program
[
  // Comment here with the date this value set was changed
  [ "value1", "value2", "value3" ],
  // Comment here with the date this value set was changed
  [ "value1", "value2", "value3" ],
  // Repeat over and over for all data
]
```

I have been parsing this for `Newtonsoft.Json` using the following code:

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    var array = JArray.Parse(sr.ReadToEnd());
    var flattened = array.SelectMany(x => x).ToArray();

    foreach (var item in flattened)
        items.Add(item.ToObject<string>());
}
```

The code above pulls each of the values that are within the JSON payload and puts them into a list called `items`.

How can I parse JSON in the format above using `System.Text.Json`?

Comment: What are you asking us?

Comment: @Enigmativity I thought it was fairly straight forward, however I have added a question mark at the end

Comment: You're asking us to write the code for you. That's usually frowned upon. Can you show us the attempt you've made and where you're stuck with that attempt?

Comment: Also, when asking for code to be written, it's a good idea to provide us much supporting code as possible. In this case, it would be great to get copy, paste, and run code that we can see `Newtonsoft.Json` in action along with the expected output from your input.

Comment: Try this: `var fin = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<string[][]>(jsonDataAsString).SelectMany(x => x);`

Comment: @Enigmativity I legit don't think you actually read this post. Two points: The question, I thought was fairly to the point and concise. Secondly, you ask for supporting code... I literally have the exact code I'm trying to rewrite above.

Comment: @Andy thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. If you'd like to add an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @Sam - You didn't ask a question. You told us a story of what you're trying to do without asking a question. Second, your code isn't complete. What is `items`?

Comment: @Enigmativity -- I think his question is *How can I parse JSON in the format above using System.Text.Json?* Currently he is using `Newtonsoft.Json`, but wants to port it to `System.Text.Json`. He wasn't sure how to load this up and have it parse the data the same way as it was in the previous JSON library. `List` looks like it would be a `List<string>` as he is deserializing arrays of strings, also it shows him using `ToObject<string>()`.

Comment: @Andy - Yes, most likely that's what it is, but the OP **didn't specifically ask** so we could only assume, and, if the OP wanted us to write the whole method, then it's starting to be a code writing service. This isn't a good question as far as this site goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To translate your code from `Newtonsoft.Json` to `System.Txt.Json`, you want to do the following:

Firstly, I see you are reading from a stream. So, I am going to dump your example to a JSON file as-is. Then I will read it in to a stream. I am also making this `async`:

```cs
using (var stream = File.OpenRead("test.json"))
{
    var multiDimentional = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<string[][]>(
        stream, new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        AllowTrailingCommas = true,
        ReadCommentHandling = JsonCommentHandling.Skip
    });

    var myArray = multiDimentional.SelectMany(x => x);

    foreach(var i in myArray)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

This will output:

```
value1
value2
value3
value1
value2
value3
```

Since your example had comments and trailing commas, I added exceptions for those scenarios.

If you don't need this `async`, then simply remove the `await` and change `DeserializeAsync` to `Deserialize`, and instead of reading from the stream, you'll have to read it to a string first. So:

```cs
var jsonAsString = File.ReadAllText("test.json");

var multiDimentional = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<string[][]>(
    jsonAsString, new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    AllowTrailingCommas = true,
    ReadCommentHandling = JsonCommentHandling.Skip
});

var myArray = multiDimentional.SelectMany(x => x);

foreach(var i in myArray)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Comment: Legend, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
var data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<List<string>>>(jsonString, new JsonSerializerOptions { AllowTrailingCommas = true });

var flattenData = data.SelectMany(item => item).ToList();
```